# Get Repeater's Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, traversal

I am trying to get all repeater's selected checkboxes of repeater's item just before page movement (pagination), and store them in some place.

```
 foreach (RepeaterItem ri in rpt.Items)
  {        
      CheckBox box = (CheckBox)ri.FindControl("chkBox");
       if (box.Checked)
       {
          ...
       }
  }
```

The problem is where do i call this function from?
I've tried to call it from ObjectDataSource1_Selected (I use objectdatasource to populate repeater) and ObjectDataSource1_Selecting but rpt.Items.Count is also 0.

rpt_PreRender() event, returns the right number of items but it happens before the selection of checkboxes and not after.

What can i do?

Comment: Try with the ItemDataBound repeater's event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the way you are looking is not possible...plz try using this code...

```
if (Repeater1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < Repeater1.Items.Count; count++)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Repeater1.Items[count].FindControl("CheckBox1");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Repeater does not have built-in Pagination (like the `GridView` or other complex controls) so it does not offer events such as the `PageIndexChanging`. I assume therefore, that you have your own Page navigation implementation. You should therefore call the function you have presented within that implemented function.

If the question was unrelated to Paging, I'd have simply suggested the `ItemDataBound/ItemCreated` events.

Comment: I can't call it inside my  Pagination function because it causes a postback, and postback clears the repeater.

Comment: ITemDatabound events work for each item, and i want to do it for all items at once.