# What in the Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

An issue has manifested in a particular area of a page I'm working on that utilizes the infamous *Repeater*.  The control is bound to a valid *Data Source* that does persist through the *View State*.

The *Repeater* code is as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="creditRightItems" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsOrder">
     <HeaderTemplate>
          <thead>
               <td>Qty Returning:</td>
               <td>Price:</td>
          </thead>
     </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
               <tr>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" PlaceHolder="0" CssClass="txtQuantity Credit-Check" data-item='<%# Eval("ProductNum") %>' /><span class="creditX">X</span></td>
                    <td><span id="ProductPrice" class='Credit-Container price<%# Eval("ProductNum") %>'><%# ConvertToMoney(Eval("Price").ToString()) %></span> 
                         <input type="hidden" id="hfPrice" value="<%# Eval("Price") %>" />
                         <input type="hidden" id="hfProdNum" value="<%# Eval("ProductNum") %>" />
                         <input type="hidden" id="hfSKU" value="<%# Eval("SKU") %>" />
                    </td>
               </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The issue occurs in code behind when I iterate through the *Repeater*.  Essentially the loop only finds two controls, which may be apart of the issue.  However, when I attempt to grab those values from code-behind they return `null`.  If I add a `runat="server"` then it will actually error the *Repeater*.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in creditRightItems.Items)
{
     TextBox inputQuantity = (TextBox)item.FindControl("txtQuantity");
     string quantity = inputQuantity.Text;

     TextBox inputProduct = (TextBox)item.FindControl("hfProdNum");
     string product = inputProduct.Text;

     HtmlInputHidden productPrice = (HtmlInputHidden)item.FindControl("hfPrice");
                        string price = productPrice.Value;

    TextBox inputSKU = (TextBox)item.FindControl("hfSKU");
    string sku = inputSKU.Text;



     if (string.Compare(quantity, "0") != 0  && string.IsNullOrEmpty(quantity))
          items.Add(new Items(product, quantity, price, sku));
}
```

The question is, **how can I get a valid value for:**

- `ProductPrice` or `hfPrice`
- `hfProdNum`
- `hfSku`

For the life of me I can't get them to return a valid content.  I've tried:

```
HiddenField productPrice = (HiddenField).item.FindControl("hfPrice");
string price = productPrice.Value;

HtmlInputHidden productPrice = (HtmlInputHidden).item.FindControl("hfPrice");
string price = productPrice.Value;
```

**I know that `FindControl` requires the `runat` so I'm trying to either achieve a way to avoid the `Repeater` breaking when I add a `runat` or a way to grab the contents of those `inputs`.**

Any thoughts and help would be terrific.

Comment: check out this previous posting.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054674/get-repeaters-items also it looks strange that your <tr><td>.... is not inside of a <table> I would personally replace them and wrap them within a <div> since a div is essentially the same thing a a `panel`

Comment: Have you try using ASP controls directly in your markup instead of HTML element? This may resolve your problem... at least I guess. Otherize... this i realy weurd as I do this kind of manipulation every single day...

Comment: @SimonDugré That is the odd thing, if I use for instance `asp:Literal` it actually errors and won't load the page.

Comment: input type hidden are <asp:HiddenField></asp:hiddenField> and span are <asp:Label></asp:Label>. See @Tim's answer.

Comment: @SimonDugré `GET http://localhost:54096/IssueCredit.aspx?oid=176232&_=1413486838849 500 (Internal Server Error)` as soon as I remove the `asp:HiddenField` or `Literal`, or `Label` it is fine.

Comment: Well, I mean, what ASP.net error you get exactly while debugging? It should fails on compilation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have in your source aren't server controls, so FindControl won't find them.

Why can't you just convert the hidden fields to asp:HiddenField tags?

```
<asp:HiddenField id='hfPrice' value='<%# Eval("Price") %>' runat='server' />
```

The runat probably isn't breaking your page; I think it's the single vs double quotes on your Eval call. If you alternate them like I have in this sample, it will work.

Comment: As I mentioned Tim, **when I do that, it breaks the repeater.**  Which doesn't allow the page to load.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the quotes with the call to eval? I've seen that break it - if you use all double quotes or all single quotes, it will break. But if you use single on the inner and double on the outer (or vice versa), it should work. Your only other option is going to be using Javascript, but you'll need to find a way to generate unique ids for them.

Comment: @Tim You should modify your answer, the whole issue with `runat` was because of the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without knowing where your code is at exactly, I guess that you should consider doing this manipulation on good event.

Try handling `ItemDataBound` event. And instead of iterating trought every Rows, do something like :

(VB.net code, sorry)

```
Private Sub myRepeater_ItemDataBound(sender as object, e as RepeaterItemEventArgs) andles myRepeater.ItemDataBound  
     If (e.Item IsNot Nothing AndAlso (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem)) Then
         ' DO STUFF HERE
         Dim productPrice As HtmlInputHidden = (HtmlInputHidden).item.FindControl("hfPrice")
         Dim price As String = productPrice.Value
     End If 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

So the culprit is due to the quotation and single quote, the error exist when:

```
value="<%# Eval("Price") %>"
```

The error no longer occurs, if you do:

```
value='<%# Eval("Price") %>'
```

Which alleviates the error in the page breaking, which allows me to properly run `FindControl`. A careless error on my part, but hopefully this helps someone in the future.